# How to use a function's variables in other functions?

Tags: reactjs

I need to get several variables declared in a function A to use it in a function B.
How can I do that with ReactJS ?

---

### EDIT

Function A :

```
 const FunctionA = (e) => {

        setPopupOpen(true)

        e.preventDefault()

        // data du cartouche en cours
        let dataDest = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data')
        let jdataDest = JSON.parse(dataDest)
        let channelDest = jdataDest.channel
        let numcartDest = jdataDest.data.NUM_CART

        // data de l'item en cours de drag
        let tot = e.dataTransfer.getData("mydatabrowser")
        if (tot) { // d&d externe depuis browser

            let dataItem = JSON.parse(tot)
            console.log(dataItem)
            console.log("drop from browser", dataItem)
            //execution d&d externe
            InsertItem(callbackDrag, props.ddo, dataItem.val.guid, channelDest, numcartDest, dataItem)

        }
        else { // d&d interne entre cartouches
             FunctionB(dataOrig, dataDest)
            }
        }

        e.dataTransfer.clearData()
        if (!tot) {
            //* 
        }
    }
```

Function B :

```
    const FunctionB = (dataOrig, dataDest) => {
        if (dataOrig, dataDest) {
            if (dndReplace) {
                ReplaceItem(callbackDrag, props.ddo, dataItem.data.GUID_ITEM, channelDest, numcartDest, dataItem)
            } else {
                InsertItem(callbackDrag, props.ddo, dataItem.val.guid, channelDest, numcartDest, dataItem)
            }
        }
    }
```

Functions A and B are in the same component.
I call the function A in a PopUp component.

Variables I need to get are dataDest and dataOrigin.

Comment: Put them all into an object and pass this as variable.

Comment: Pass it as a prop assuming A and B are FCs.

Comment: Please clarify the context of your problem like Function A and Function B are in same component or they are in different components?

Answer (score 0):

Assign all variables to Array or Object and pass it as parameter to the function B, if the function B is a functional component then you can pass it as props.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code so we can solve it and explain the solution with your code as an example :)